# hover для дочерних элементов, как сделать?

Tags: css

Как сделать что бы при на ведении на родительский элемент мышью срабатывал hover  на все его дочерние элементы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На какие конкретно здесь должен срабатывать?

Comment: Код элементов и картинку с ожидаемым результатом в студию

Comment: Указывать отдельно дочерние элементы к примеру в sass
`.block:hover { .block-1 { *hover-effect*} {.block-2 { *hover-effect*}};`